# Can't Start Server for Rails on Windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following the instructions on installrails.com I get to the point where I attempt to start a server and it returns this

```
$ rails server
e:/Programs/Ruby/Rails Installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/ge
ms/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:37:in `exec': No such file or di
rectory - "e:/Programs/Ruby/Rails Installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.ex
e" (Errno::ENOENT)
        from e:/Programs/Ruby/Rails Installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/
gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:37:in `block in exe
c_app_rails'
        from e:/Programs/Ruby/Rails Installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/
gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `loop'
        from e:/Programs/Ruby/Rails Installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/
gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `exec_app_rai
ls'
        from e:/Programs/Ruby/Rails Installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/
gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from e:/Programs/Ruby/Rails Installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/
2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from e:/Programs/Ruby/Rails Installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/
2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from e:/Programs/Ruby/Rails Installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/
gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from e:/Programs/Ruby/Rails Installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rails
:23:in `load'
        from e:/Programs/Ruby/Rails Installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rails
:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure what to make of it and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

That installer uses an old version of rails anyway, so try something else:

1. You can install [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/).  Then install [rails](http://rubyonrails.org/).
2. Or, if that is too complex, Engine Yard(a big name in the rails ecosphere) has an up-to-date one click [ruby+rails+other_useful_stuff installer](http://railsinstaller.org/en) that you can try.
3. Or, checkout the [rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-up_and_running) setup:

> ...new users are encouraged to sidestep such installation and configuration issues by using a cloud integrated development environment. The cloud IDE runs inside
>   an ordinary web browser and hence works the same across different
>   platforms, which is especially useful for operating systems (such as
>   Windows) on which Rails development has historically been difficult.